# Exotic life in a brown dwarf

Tags: xenobiology, astrophysics

From what I have seen in the discussions here about possible life on brown dwarfs, it’s concluded that no complex chemical life (even metallic or CNT based ones) can survive the radiation and gravity in these pseudo-stars.

If not traditional microbes or nanites, I wonder if star inhabitants could be kilometer-sized masses of thousands of convection cells (like the Qax in Stephen Baxter’s Xeelee Sequence). Or are such structures too fragile in the brown dwarfs convection currents?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what the consensus is, but I would encourage reading of the following article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.11410.pdf

Comment: Robert L Forward's book "Dragon's Egg" is possibly also of interest.  The problem for non-solid stars is the lack of stable surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.science.org/content/article/alien-life-could-thrive-clouds-failed-stars

The gravity might present an issue, but lifeforms evolve to fit their environment. A whale’s body cannot support its mass on land, but it does fine in water. A floating (in either air or water) lifeform of some type is the most likely to survive and thrive as it does not have to contend with gravity to the same degree as a surface-based lifeform.

The radiation from a brown dwarf is mostly infrared. A young brown dwarf might be a bit hotter and radiate more, but after it radiates this heat and cools down, it would present less of an issue.
https://chandra.harvard.edu/xray_sources/browndwarf_fg.html
“The absence of X-rays from LP 944-20 during the non flaring period is also a significant result. It sets the lowest observational limit on steady X-ray power produced by a brown dwarf star, and shows that million degree Celsius upper atmospheres, or coronas, cease to exist as the surface temperature of a brown dwarf cools below about 2500 degrees Celsius and becomes electrically neutral.”

If having lifeforms thriving on a brown dwarf is important for your story, or would simply make it better, then you can put them in there. Even if it is highly unlikely, it will eventually happen somewhere.

Hypothetical BD-1
A BD forms in a system and consumes most of the extra mass not captured by the system’s star. One other small rocky planet exists, as do a smattering of asteroids in a loose belt. The BD is initially very hot and radiates this heat away over a billion years. Eventually, its x-ray phase begins to end and becomes intermittent. Comets occasionally enter the gravitational pull of the BD and evaporate to add a layer of water vapor to the atmosphere.

Having cooled to the point where life is possible, and containing the building blocks of life, it is only a matter of time. During one of the x-ray outbursts, the energy causes certain chemical chains to bond and form a new lifeform. This lifeform is capable of reproducing and slowly begins to do so. After a few decades, the x-ray burst again occurs and breaks apart the lifeforms floating through the clouds. This happens several more times over the next several million years. There comes a point in time where some of the lifeforms which have arisen resists being killed off by the x-ray bursts, which are becoming less and less frequent. A tipping point is reached, and the BD no longer emits x-rays. This leaves the atmosphere free and clear for colonization.

For a billion years, nothing much happens. The clouds are filled with a simple lifeform which consumes atmospheric chemicals and reproduces. Then one day, the system’s star sends out a solar flair which impacts the BD. The radiation sterilizes a large portion of the BD’s surface facing the star. In a few of the single-celled lifeforms, an error in their genetic code causes them to fail to replicate properly. Instead of splitting into two single-celled organisms, the cells fuse together and form the first multi-cellular lifeform in that environment. Within a million years, the clouds have been taken over by several different variations of the lifeform. Some rise into the upper atmosphere to make use of the weak sunlight, while others drift lower and feed on the richer cloud layers. A lifeform evolves the capability to consume other lifeforms and metabolize their nutrients. This kicks off an arms race as the various species try to adapt to the threat.

Time continues, and life finds a way.

Hypothetical BD-2

This BD is ejected from its stellar nursery shortly after its formation. It begins a long trip through the empty void of space, radiating what little heat it generates. It is set to continue its path through the darkness when it encounters a rogue planet. The planet becomes trapped in the gravity well of the BD and is slowly drawn in. Tidal forces impart a vicious spin on the planet, causing it to rotate rapidly as it is pulled into an ever-tightening spiral. Friction heats up the surface of the planet, causing frozen water to boil. When it is all said and done, the planet sits at the center of the BD, much smaller than it used to be but still a decent size.

Extremophiles, which had been thriving deep underground in geothermal vents, are scattered through the clouds. All die as a result in the change of environment, but there are survivors in underground pockets on the planet. These lifeforms spread upwards to colonize the warm surface and begin to utilize the thick atmosphere as a source of energy. After a few million years, the BD cools below the condensation point of water and the vapor in the atmosphere rains back down to the surface.  This results in a small planet covered in an ocean of hot water. The extremophiles’ population explodes in numbers and the waters team with life.

A billion years later and the waters have cooled to that of a warm bath. Extremophiles still thrive near ocean thermal vents, but the water is filled with various lifeforms living out their days in total darkness. Using infrared photosynthesis, plants cover the oceans in a thick mat. Water bear type lifeforms chew on the plants and flee when they sense the vibrations of a predator. Mycelium like strands reach out of the water to colonize the shores and release acidic solutions which dissolves the rock to release trapped nutrients. The resulting nutrient rich mud flats are thick with algae and the worms which feed on it. In the distant future (two billion years) the waters will cool to the point where the surface will freeze over. Until then, the surface is a hidden paradise drifting through space.